# What does「散々人を待たせておいて最初の一言がそれか」mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I am unsure how to translate the following phrase:

> [散々]{さんざん}人{ひと}を待{ま}たせておいて最初{さいしょ}の一言{ひとこと}がそれか

My guess as to how this phrase translates is:

> Is that the first thing people say to those who are waiting for them?

Is there a better way to translate this phrase?

Comment: How is your translation looking so far? ^^;

Comment: Ehm... I'm not sure... I guess is something like "is that the first thing people say to those who are waiting for them?"

Comment: So is there a certain part of that phrase that you are unsure about?

Comment: all, I wasn't sure about my translation.

Answer (score 4):

In contrast with user1205935's answer, I got the impression that 最初の一言 refers to the first words that *were* said and not the first words that *should be* said. If I were to insert an extra clarifying part into the Japanese, it would be

> 散々人を待たせておいて、**（鈍感な）お前が言った**最初の一言がそれか

and not

> 散々人を待たせておいて、**気が効いてる礼儀正しい人の**最初の一言がそれか

so I would translate liberally as

> You kept me(/a person) waiting all this time, and that's the first thing out of your mouth?

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is, why it is "in contrast" to my answer. I understand the question in my answer to be rhetorical, about what _was_ said, not about what _should be_ said. In any case, you seem to have been more successful at putting that point across.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I would translate differently is the causative form 待たせる, which doesn't mean just waiting, but to keep so. waiting.

> 散々人を待たせておいて最初の一言がそれか
>   Is that the first thing to say to people after keeping them flat out waiting?